# Justify Kendo UI Chart

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  categoryAxis: [{
    justified: true,
    categories: ["2012", "2013"]
  }],
  series: [
    { type: "line", data: [1, -2, 3] },
    { type: "bar", data: [1, -2, 3] }
  ]
});
</script>
```

I would like to use `categoryAxis.Justify : true`, but it seems like it's not supported when adding a bar chart. Any idea how I can justify my chart so that it does not start from center? Thanks